# Ionic serve 404 failed to load main.js and main.css resources

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been experiencing a really weird issue recently with my ionic 2 / angular 2 project. I am getting a blank white screen and 404 for main.js and main.css as shown below, when trying to use the `ionic serve` command.  Whats odd,  is this code compiled fine and loaded the app just fine a few moments ago. Nothing has changed from a non-generated code perspective. Also, I haven't installed any new plugins / made any updates recently.

```
404 GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.css 
404 GET http://localhost:8100/build/main.js
```

Has any one experienced this issue in the past? Any suggestions on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did the `build/main.css` file generate in the `www/` directory?

Comment: Every once in a while you'll get strange bugs that don't make sense, clean your build folder and run a fresh build. It usually works.

Comment: @inspired, no, my `www/build/` directory do not contain the `main.css` or `main.js` files. How can I force them to generate?

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the reply. How can I 'clean' my build folder and run a fresh build?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend the easy (one time) way is to just delete everything in the folder. If you want it to always happen, you gotta edit your build process.

Comment: @Matt, so I deleted the /www/build/ directory and ran `ionic serve` and I am getting the same error. The build directory only contains `polyfills.js` as it did prior to deleting.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I think it's an RC0 issue. There's a question on the Ionic forums that may help you: [Random 404 Error](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/main-js-main-css-giving-404-not-found-error-randomly-rc0/65239/15)

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused by error in your typescript file. Most notably declaring a variable of type array like this:

```
arrayName: []
```

The proper way to declare a variable of type Array is any one of the following:

```
arrayName: Array<Object>
arrayName: Array<string>
arrayName: Array<number>
```

...`arrayName: Array<any>`

Typescript will "silently fail" if declared otherwise

Answer (score -1):

For me there was an issue while declaring the below variable.

projectList:[] = [];

Not sure why this is happening, but remove that resolve that issue.